# How would I go about image labeling/Classification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, classification

Let's say I have a set of images of passports. I am working on a project where I have to identify the name on each passport and eventually transform that object into text.

For the very first part of labeling (or classification (I think. beginner here)) where the name is on each passport, how would I go about that?

What techniques / software can I use to accomplish this?

in great detail or any links would be great. I'm trying to figure out how this is done exactly so I can began coding

I know training a model is involved possibly but I'm just not sure

I'm using Python if that matters.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's two routes you can take, one where you have labeled data (or you want to label data yourseld), and one where you don't have that.

Let's start with the latter. Say you have an image of a passport. You want to detect where the text in the image is, and what that text says. You can achieve this using a library called `pytessaract`. It's an AI that does exactly this for you. It works well because it has been trained on a lot of other images, so it's good in detecting text in *any* image.

If you have labels you might be able to improve your model you could make with `pytessaract`, but this is *a lot* harder. If you want to learn it anyway, I would recommend with learning `ŧensorflow`, and use "transfer learning" to improve your model.

Comment: Thank you for that! how would I go about labeling the images myself?

Comment: and what if I want to iabel the images myself

Comment: For the actual labeling, you would want to draw bounding boxes around the text in the images and mark for each bounding box what text is in it.

Comment: So when I do the labeling, let’s say I’m working with 2000 images for instance and I label 500. Would I be labeling the text that I want so that I would be able to provide training so the rest could be labeled automatically using machine learning?

Comment: If you start from scratch (i.e. you don't use transfer learning), 500 images will not be enough to do plain (no extra processing) text detection. If you do use transfer learning, 500 extra images might make it a bit better, but it won't make much of a difference. I know you asked for classific, but I don't think you need that here. Because passports are - well - passports I would just seperate all the letters using `numpy`, and recognize each letter individually, either by using a simple pre trained model or even comparing it to a template (because all the passports (might) have the same font.